# TortoiseSVN email notification for old branches

Tags: tortoisesvn

I would like to receive email notifications at the beginning of each month with a list of any branches that haven't had a commit in over 2 months. Currently, one of our developers manually checks these branches and either moves them to a different space or deletes the branch entirely. Are there any third party tools, features within tortoisesvn, or types of server-side hooks I can implement to automate this process?

Comment: Yes, you would implement this via a server-side hook script.

Comment: @alroc - it's bad idea for hook, because it's a task of (month?) cronjob, but yes, as server-side job

Comment: not related to TortoiseSVN at all, re-tag is needed